# Topology exercises - closure, frontier

Tags: general-topology

Are my proofs correct? The topology is $\mathbb{R^n}$

**Exercises.**

1. Prove that a set $A$ is closed iff $Fr(A)\subseteq A$
2. A set $A$ is closed iff $A=Cl(A)$
3. For any set, $A$, $Fr(A)$ is closed
4. For any set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, $Fr(A)=Fr(\mathbb{R^n}-A)$
5. For any set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, $Fr(A)=Cl(A)\cap Cl(\mathbb{R^n}-A)$
6. A set $A$ is open iff $A=Int(A)$

**Proofs.** The closure of a set $A$ is defined by $Cl(A)=A\cup Fr(A)$

1. Suppose $Fr(A)\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}-A$. As $A$ is closed, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R^n}-A, \exists N_x$ such that $N_x\cap A=\emptyset$. This is true for every $x\in Fr(A)$ (by assumption). But $x\in Fr(A) \implies$ every neighborhood of $x$ intersect $A$ non-trivially; a contradiction. So $Fr(A)\subseteq A$. Conversely, suppose $Fr(A)\subseteq A$ and let $x\notin A$, then $\exists N$ neighborhood of $x$ such that $N\cap A=\emptyset$ thus $A$ is closed.
2. Suppose $A$ is closed, then $Fr(A)\subseteq A \implies Fr(A)\cup A \subseteq A \implies Cl(A)\subseteq A$. As $A\subseteq Cl(A)$ for any $A$, it follows that $A=Cl(A)$. Conversely, suppose $A=Cl(A)=A\cup Fr(A)$, then $Fr(A)\subseteq A$ thus $A$ is closed (by the previous result).
3. As $Fr(Fr(A))\subseteq Fr(A)$, it follows (by 1.) that $Fr(A)$ is closed.
4. Let $x\in Fr(A)$, then $\exists$ neighborhood $N$ such that $N\cap A\neq \emptyset$ and $N\cap (\mathbb{R^n}-A)\neq \emptyset$. As $A=\mathbb{R^n}-(\mathbb{R^n}-A)$, it follows that $N\cap (\mathbb{R^n}-(\mathbb{R^n}-A))\neq \emptyset$ and $N\cap (\mathbb{R^n}-)\neq \emptyset$ thus $x\in Fr(\mathbb{R^n}-A)$. The converse can be proved similarily.
5. $Cl(A)\cap Cl(\mathbb{R^n}-A) = (A\cup Fr(A))\cap ((\mathbb{R^n}-A)\cup Fr(A))=Fr(A)\cup (A\cap (\mathbb{R^n}-A))=Fr(A)$
6. Suppose $A=Int(A)$. As $Int(A)$ is a union of open sets it's open thus $A$ is open. Conversely, suppose that $A$ is open, then there is an open neighborhood of every point $x\in A$ such that $x\in N\subseteq A$. As $x\in N$, $x$ is in any union of open sets containing $N$ so $x\in Int(A)$. As $Int(A)\subseteq A$ for any $A$, it follows that $A=Int(A)$

Comment: There was a stray $\$$ sign which messed up everything after your proof in (3). All I did was to remove that $\$$-sign.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you! I have a slow computer, rendering takes time.

Comment: I would prove $5$ before proving $4$, since $5\implies 4$. Do you see why?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Replace $A$ by $\mathbb{R^n}-A$? I blindly followed the order in the book.

Comment: In #$1$, $Fr(A)\not\subseteq A$ doesn't imply $Fr(A)\subseteq \Bbb R^n-A$, but rather $Fr(A)\cap (\Bbb R^n-A)\neq\varnothing$. Your argument still works, but I thought I'd throw this out there.

Comment: @saadtaame Aha. =)

Comment: @Clayton The whole space is $\mathbb{R^n}$, Isn't it so that if a set is not in some $B$, then it should be in its complement? It makes sense to me

Comment: To say $Fr(A)\not\subseteq A$ simply means there exists $x\in Fr(A)$ with $x\notin A$.

Comment: @Clayton So $x$ is in the complement of $A$

Comment: @saadtaame: The difference is that it is a singular $x$, not every $x$. See Brian M. Scott's answer for more clarification as to why your negation isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\fr}{\operatorname{Fr}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$You get off on the wrong foot in the proof of (1): the negation of $\fr(A)\subseteq A$ is $\fr(A)\nsubseteq A$, **not** the much stronger statement $\fr(A)\subseteq\Bbb R^n\setminus A$. For that direction of the equivalence you can argue as follows:

> Suppose that $A$ is closed and $x\notin A$; then $x$ has a nbhd $N$ such that $N\cap A=\varnothing$. This clearly implies that $x\notin\fr(A)$, and it follows at once that $\fr(A)\subseteq A$.

For (3) I take it that you’ve already shown elsewhere that $\fr(\fr(A))\subseteq\fr(A)$ for any set $A$.

In (4) you have the wrong quantifier: if $x\in\fr(A)$, then for **every** nbhd $N$ of $x$ it’s true that $N\cap A\ne\varnothing\ne N\cap(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)$, and you need this fact for every nbhd of $x$, not for just one, in order for your argument actually to yield the conclusion that $x\in\fr(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)$.

The rest looks fine, however.

Comment: Is the stronger statement wrong?

Comment: @saadtaame: Yes, in the sense that it does not follow from the assumption that $\fr(A)\nsubseteq A$. Since at that point all you’re assuming is that $\fr(A)\nsubseteq A$, and that assumption does not imply that $\fr(A)\cap A=\varnothing$, it’s incorrect to assume that $\fr(A)\cap A=\varnothing$.